# Implementing dword type as a subclass of Javascript Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, inheritance

I need to implement extended precision <strike>boolean</strike> binary arithmetic, and I figured I could use classes to create types for DWORD and "MULTIWORD".

Is there anything wrong with doing it like this? Seems to be working.

P.S. I would prefer to stay within the ES5 (pre *class*) paradigm.

```
// not production code
var DoubleWord = JSClass.Extends(Array, function(initx) {
    DoubleWord.baseConstructor.call(this, initx);

    // offset naught padding
    var initoffset = 0;

    this.s = 32; // (s)ize in bits

    if (initx)
        for (var i = 0; i < initx.length; i++)
            this.push(initx[i]);

    initoffset = this.length; // pointless, descriptional

    for (var i = initoffset; i < this.s; i++)
        this.push(0);
});
```

<strike>(ignore the `JSClass` thing)</strike>
Here is the JSClass.Extends inheritance implementation

```
JSClass = {};

JSClass.Extends = function(baseClass, constructor) {
    Inheritance = function() {};

    Inheritance.prototype = baseClass.prototype;
    constructor.prototype = new Inheritance();
    constructor.prototype.constructor = constructor;
    constructor.baseConstructor = baseClass;
    constructor.superClass = baseClass.prototype;

    return constructor;
};
```

Comment: "*ignore the `JSClass` thing*" - well, yeah, that's the part that looks wrong. Especially since you specifically asked about `Array` subclassing.

Comment: Some smells: a) it's unclear what you mean by "*precision boolean arithmetic*", but if it means creating large arrays of boolean values then that sounds inefficient b) why are you passing `initx` to the base constructor? c) `.s` is not a good name d) if `initx` is longer than 32, the code probably doesn't do what you want e) the `initoffset` variable appears pointless

Comment: @Bergi a) I stand corrected; extended precision _binary_ arithmetic. b) Got this from a tutorial; I thought I need to pass _all_ params to base constructor. c) true; it is size in bits, d) the logic is to enforce real-world operations by convention e) it is pointless but it's _not_ production code...

Comment: Thanks for adding `JSClass.Extends` code. That way of inheriting is pretty outdated… and [doesn't work with `Array`](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/). If you really want/need to subclass `Array`, use ES6 `class` syntax

Comment: you do know that modern JS now has a [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) class?

Comment: @Bergi Cheers. I've skimmed through _perfectionkills_ article; seemed too advanced, thus the question. I am avoiding _class_ syntax for now, lest I lose touch with prototype mechanism, which I find very useful for understanding OO principles in general.

Comment: @Alnitak yes, very much, but this code is a part of my personal virtual machine emulation, and I am also implementing some crypto stuff, so I need to work with bits.

Comment: @Hatebit the bitwise boolean operators are usable with `BigInt`.   They are almost certainly faster than anything you might write in JS itself.

Comment: @Alnitak you got a point. This is a study, though, and I am trying to figure out the underworks so I can better understand it. **The question is more about Array inheritance**

Comment: @Hatebit If you don't completely understand that article, then heed the advice that for array subclassing you **need** `class` syntax. If you want to learn more about prototype mechanisms, then use `Object.create` in that `Extends` code, and use it to inherit from some classes that are not built-in.

Comment: @Hatebit then you probably need to re-write the question somewhat.   Your first version said _"Ignore the JSClass bit"_ but now you're saying that's the most important part of the question...